# Is 'how cold' natural?

Tags: exclamatives

If someone acts very indifferently towards an invitation, is the exclamation 'how cold' natural?

For example:

> Alice (trying to act as if she's not scheming): Would you like a glass of wine?
>
> Bob (suspiciously): What's the real deal here?
>
> Alice: How cold.

(Alice has feelings for Bob, but Bob doesn't. They are alone in a room of a bar, where Alice invited Bob to, saying that they need to talk. The conversation happens on Bob's arrival.)

Comment: Did you invent that example yourself?

Comment: Just as being invited to share a warm fire (in a cold time of the year) makes us feel comfortable, included, etc, so does kind behaviour by others. Being kept away from the fire so we feel cold makes us feel uncomfortable and excluded. So we use adjectives of temperature to describe human behaviour.

Comment: The context needs more details...  yes, perhaps natural enough in context, what we dont' see is the body language, the lighting, the whole relationship between Alice and Bob.  So the question "is it natural" is totally unanswerable.  (however see the comment by Michael) What is your real aim here? Are you writing fiction? Have you been in this situation? Are you creating a situation for the sake of study??

Comment: @JamesK The example is taken from a video translation sub. I'm not sure if the simple two-words 'how cold' is a collocation a native speaker would use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bob using "how cold" would be used in this context ironically just to embarrass Alice.

As in your newest edit, you mentioned Alice has feelings for Bob, but not vice versa.

"how cold" could be used here, but Bob's reply might not really be *cold enough* for this reply.

If Bob said:

> What do you think you're doing? Do you really believe that you can take advantage of a mature man by getting him drunk?

Than it would definitely be cold, Bob would be considered "cold-hearted".

Answer (score 1):

So, as someone who lives in America, this would only be used sarcastically or teasingly. It wouldn't work if you were saying it unironically.

Comment: Can you deepen and explain your answer a little?

Answer (score 1):

You might describe someone or their behavior as **cold** if it's without emotion or compassion, but usually in an insulting way and often using an insult that might be considered unfair. I'm not sure that Bob's reply is insulting enough to qualify as **cold**, but it probably all depends on the relationship between Alice and Bob.

If Bob had replied something like, "Is this the poor waitress trying to get the rich boy drunk and take advantage of him?", to me that would be cold.

Someone who exhibits this kind of behavior is often referred to as **cold-hearted**.

Answer (score 1):

The use of "how cold" in that context would seem to me plausible in two situations, if Alice and Bob were in a quite close relationship -- say, brother and sister -- so suspicions can be treated as insulting, or if Alice were prone to emotional manipulation by pretending they are closer than they are.